# jQuery Submit Event Happens Twice

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery, double-submit-problem

My jQuery `submit()` event is firing twice, and I don't know why.

I'm using a templating engine to build my HTML dynamically so I end up calling `$(document).ready()` multiple times, as follows...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.search input[type='image']").click(function() { $(this).closest('form.search').submit() })
})
</script>
```

...later...

```
</script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    # I have put an `unbind('submit')` in here to be sure I have nothing else but this particular function bound to `submit`
    $('form.search').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        search_term = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val()
        $new_keyword = $('<li class="filter keyword selected" name="'+search_term+'">'+search_term+'</li>')
        alert('event fired!')
        $("#keywords ul").append($new_keyword)
        do_search_selected()
        return false; // Stop the form from actually submitting
    })
})
</script>
```

The Form HTML:

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="/search/">

    <div>
        <input id="searchfield"type="text" name="keywords" value="Search" />
        <input id="searchbutton" type="image" src="{{ media_url }}images/search.png" />
     </div>
</form>
```

(**FYI:** When I run this in the Safari console `$('form.search').get()` I get this `[
<form class=​"search" method=​"get" action=​"/​search/​">​…​</form>​
]`)

The problem:

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the submit button or otherwise trigger the `submit` event, the event is fired twice. I know this because an `<li>` is added twice to the dom and the `alert` appears twice as well.

The culprit:

When I comment out the `click` event binding in the first `$(document).ready` call, the event only occurs once, as expected. How can the code in the first be causing the double event trigger?

Comment: Is it possible the selector `form.search` is not returning what you expect?

Comment: Also post the button code that this is bound to.  If you have a sample page you might put a link to that as well.

Comment: Is the submit for the form bound to the submit button and/or to the submit event of the form?

Comment: @RSG I believe it's returning what I want, please see my edit. (I'm supposed to bind to the `<form>` element, right?)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  What's in do_search_selected()?

Comment: @RSG it does an AJAX query. I just tried commenting it out and the event still triggers twice.

Comment: I discovered some Javascript that when removed, makes the double event triggering go away, but I can't figure out WHY it's causing the problem!! I made a big edit to re-describe the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in the first `$(document).ready()` function. I bound the `click` event of an `input[type=image]` to trigger a `submit` event on my form, but it turns out that image inputs already do a `submit` when clicked by default.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the form and preventing the default submit handler should all work as you describe it.  I'm fairly certain an unrelated error (Maybe in `do_search_selected()`?) is preventing the call from reaching 'return false' which causes the form to submit as normal.

**Edit**

Just saw you last comment.  You can test this by running just the selector, an alert, and the override.  If you're using AJAX asynchronously in that function you may need to set `async`.

Also, add semicolons to the end of your statements!